# Where to find Blazor javascript functions documentation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Where to find blazor javascript functions documentation
Example:

`Blazor._internal.navigationmanager.navigateto(url,false,true);`

As i know that the first boolean is to make a reload or not
But the second boolean i dont know what is it for

So where can i find a documentation for blazor functions that can be called directly form javascript?

Comment: Why are you trying to call these functions?  They are internal for a reason, as they are the under the hood implementation for higher level abstractions such as `NavigationManager`.

Comment: For better blazor performance  there are many developer who are going this deep such as the one who created hybrid blazor (switching between server and wasm at run time ) which take the advantages of both models he uses the same method i wrote  but how did he found  it /where to look ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the javascript function directly, you are supposed to call through .NET Interop.

It works like this:

```
DotNet.invokeMethod('myproject', 'MethodNameInStaticClass', myParameter);
```

- `myproject` is the name of your project in Blazor.
- `MethodNameInStaticClass` is a static method with the `[JSInvokable]` attribute. It can be in any class.
- `myParameter` is the parameter passed on to the function call, maybe a json string, depending on your needs.

Read more about it here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-7.0

However, you mention performance in the question and it should be mentioned that if the parameter size is very big (like a base64 encoded image) then the call may take several seconds.